# Drone tilts before it takes off

Tags: drone.io, mission-planner

I'm having a problem with my DIY drone for a very long time. The problem is that the drone's motors work properly and evenly in the motor test, but whenever I try to operate it with the remote controller, the drone tilts and flips before it takes off.

Video footage of issue:
https://media.giphy.com/media/YjgL3A593olD2BVnz7/giphy.gif

I'm pretty sure the motors and propeller directions are correct. I also made all the esc and pdb connections properly. I also performed the calibrations. I've repurchased all the parts, collected and mounted them again and still have the same problem.

Parts that i use in;
-Pixhawk 2.4.8 Flight Controller
-Matek PDB
-FlySky F6iX RC ve 10 channel receiver
-Emax Mt2212 II bldc motor
-Simon Series 30A Esc
-Power Xtra 2200mAh 20C Li-po Battery
-Ublox M8N GPS

Comment: FYI, [drone.io](https://www.drone.io) is a CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery) platform, unrelated to drones. Pretty sure you selected the wrong tag.